# Vague Job Description

Tags: professionalism

Currently I am a part time scheduler for a nursing home.  My job description states that I am required to take shifts with our customers as needed, meaning if a companion calls out I'm to cover their shift.  We are constantly hiring, and continue to be short staffed. I've been informed that I'm required to take all shifts that cannot be covered due to lack of companions.  I refused and was written up for insubordination.  My question is, what shall I do moving forward.  I make 11/hour and would be required to drive over 40 miles for a possible 2 hour shift.  If the customer decides they only want me for an hour I'm paid for the hour I worked rather than the 2 hour minimum the customer is required to pay.  I wasn't hired to be a housekeeper and that is what the shifts are primarily.  How shall I proceed?

Comment: Location will be an important aspect of any answer. Can you add a location tag to the question?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you need help with. Are you upset about covering multiple shifts? Are you upset that you have to travel 40 miles for 2 hours of work? Are you upset that you're a housekeeper? Are you upset that customers cut short of 2 hours? Please expand on what aspect you need help in and what you done prior that failed?

Answer (score 2):

> I've been informed that I'm required to take all shifts that cannot be
>   covered due to lack of companions. I refused and was written up for
>   insubordination. My question is, what shall I do moving forward.

It appears that you will take all shifts that cannot be covered or you will eventually be fired.

> I wasn't hired to be a housekeeper and that is what the shifts are
>   primarily. How shall I proceed?

Unless you are in union, or local laws prohibit the actions of your employer, you'll need to decide how much you want/need this job.

If you decide you no longer want to cover shifts or do housekeeping, you should find a new job, give your notice, then leave this one.

Answer (score 1):

> We are constantly hiring, and continue to be short staffed.
>
> I refused and was written up for insubordination.

Are these not clues to what is expected of you and what they think of you?

> How shall I proceed?

That's for you to decide. As it stands you either accept their terms or you don't and risk being terminated and stranded.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it doesn't look like your job description is very vague at all.

> My job description states that I am required to take shifts with our customers as needed

And then

> I'm required to take all shifts that cannot be covered due to lack of companions

Your customers need companions. You are paid to be a companion. Due to your company's lack of planning/low wages/bad business practices/whatever, they are having issues retaining staff. Despite this, your role does not change. You need to assist those customers. Unfortunately, this means you don't get the luxury of picking and choosing which ones you assist. The issue of driving 40 miles has no bearing on the professional responsibility you agreed to.

Your options are (as I see it):

1 - Continue on as you have been, while bringing the issue to your managements attention

2 - Follow the lead of people who have left and whose holes you're filling and quit

Unless there's a union or contract involved, there's no legal way to make your job better. Find a new job.